# Como contar a quantidade de elementos inputs dentro de uma div

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Usando o Asp.net MVC, estou criando um os inputs dinamicamente usando um loop com os dados di banco.

```
<div class="col-md-12" id="div-contatos">

    @if (Model.PessoasContatosViewModel != null)
    {
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.PessoasContatosViewModel.Count; i++)
        {


            <div class="form-group row align-items-center">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PessoasContatosViewModel[i].Id, new { @class = "hid-id" })
                    <label asp-for="PessoasContatosViewModel[i].ContatoTipoId" class="control-label sel-contatoTipo">Tipo de Contato</label>
                    <select asp-for="PessoasContatosViewModel[i].ContatoTipoId" asp-items="Model.ContatosTipos" data-plugin="selectpicker" title="Selecione uma opção" class="form-control show-tick show-menu-arrow sel-contatoTipo"></select>
                    <span asp-validation-for="PessoasContatosViewModel[i].ContatoTipoId" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <label asp-for="PessoasContatosViewModel[i].Contato" class="control-label txt-contato">Contato</label>
                    <input type="text" asp-for="PessoasContatosViewModel[i].Contato" class="form-control txt-contato" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="PessoasContatosViewModel[i].Contato" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label asp-for="PessoasContatosViewModel[i].Detalhes" class="control-label txt-detalhes">Detalhes</label>
                    <textarea asp-for="PessoasContatosViewModel[i].Detalhes" class="form-control txt-detalhes"></textarea>

                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <label class="control-label">&nbsp;</label>
                    <div class="checkbox-custom checkbox-default">
                        <input type="checkbox" asp-for="PessoasContatosViewModel[i].ContatoPrincipal" class="ckb-contatoPrincipal" checked autocomplete="off" />
                        <label asp-for="PessoasContatosViewModel[i].ContatoPrincipal" class=" ckb-contatoPrincipal">Contato Principal</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-icon btn-default btn-outline btn-remover-contato" data-id="@Model.PessoasContatosViewModel[i].Id" style="margin-top: 30px;"><i class="icon wb-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        }

    }

</div>
```

Usando o JavaScript, quando clico no botão Adicionar contato, preciso saber quantos inputs tenho dentro da minha div-contatos. Para isso, estou usando o JS:

```
var itemIndex = $("#div-contatos input.iHidden").length;
```

O Problema é que não está funcionando. O Retorno está sendo 0. O que está errado?

Comment: Você já tentou da seguinte maneira?     
var count = $("body").find("div-contatos").length;

Comment: Testei com sua sujestão @VictorLaio, mas tb obtive 0 como retorno...estranho...

Comment: Uma outra alternativa entao é a seguinte: document.getElementsByClassName('div-contatos').length

Comment: Mesma coisa... Estou com sérios problemas rssr

Comment: Se eu deixar apenas $("#div-contatos").length; ele consegue retornar 1... Ele encontra a div... Será não é alguma coisa relacionada aos campos serem criados com asp.net razor no qual input.iHidden não esteja funcionando? @VictorLaio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está rendenizando o seguinte html:

```
<input type="text" asp-for="PessoasContatosViewModel[i].Contato" class="form-control txt-contato" />
```

Seu input possui duas classes: **form-control** e **txt-contato**. Porém, em seu javascript, está contando a quantidade de elementos com a classe **iHidden**.

Tente dessa forma:

```
var itemIndex = $("#div-contatos input.txt-contato").length;
```

Comment: Publiquei um exemplo aqui: https://jsfiddle.net/f8xah39m/1/

Comment: Funcionou @Bruno Soares!!!! Agora entendi a ídeia... Muito obrigado!!! :)